# Amazon API product in java

Tags: java, api, amazon-product-api

I'm new here,
I'm trying to make a java program let the user input Item ID(Amazon product) then return price and shipping details.
I search a lot I got lost there I'm beginner could someone help me please :)

edit: 
what I want is how I make my program search in Amazon by ItemID(Amazon product) then return price of product.

Comment: Can you post this comment as an answer?

Comment: @xtratic, I believe the OP is trying to use Amazon.com product services, not AWS IMHO.

Comment: @Cascader Thanks for catching that, I didn't read carefully enough. Same idea applies though.

Comment: I believe instead of down voting the questions for new comers we should help them understand the community and its usage and evolve with them as well. Regarding question , please review [Amazon Product Advertising API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html)

Comment: @AbdullahObeid This site is more about questions and answers regarding specific programming problems. It's a bit too broad to ask how to get started with a language or idea here. However, if you try language examples or start writing your target program and run into problems with your code, asking here would be a great way to get an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point would be the [Amazon Marketplace Web Service](https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html) site. It provides content for developers willing to use Amazon (not AWS) product services.